# How to write an "if/then" formula from a single cell referring to a range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an if/then in one cell (E12) that refers to a range of 2 other columns.
Basically, I have sheet that is listing fees for various banks. When the cell with the bank name (F1 - which is a dropdown of about 12 banks) is listing a particular bank, I want E12 to list that bank's respective fee. I have the list of the 12 banks and their respective fees in F42:F56 and E42:E56.

In E12 I wrote: `=IF(F1=F42,E42,"0")` worked fine, but just for one bank (the first one listed).
Again, F1 is a dropdown of bank names sourced from F42:F56.
E42:E56 are the respective fees.

I tried `=IF(F1=F42:F56,E42:E56,"0"`) and it returned a #VALUE error.

So I instead manually entered all 12 IF statements as nested IFs, and it worked, but it's a very long, ridiculous formula. Also, nested IF is really for when there are different conditions.

`=IF(F1=F42,E42,"0")` where F1 is the bank name dropdown, F42:F56 is the bank name and source (for the name dropdown in F1) and E42:E56 is that bank's fee.

When I tried `=IF(F1=F42:F56,E41,"0")` I thought it'd just "drag" on the original `=IF(F1=F42,E42,"0")` and work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a combination of `index` and `match`

`Match` will find the row number where the lookup value is in the range specified. The 0 denotes an absolute match.
`Index` will then return the value from the range at the row and column specified.

`=INDEX(E42:F56,MATCH(F1,F42:F56,0),1)`

Comment: Hey that worked!! Thank you so much! I searched all over the web and couldn't find anything close to a working answer. Thank you so much! I'd upvote you but apparently I'm too new to do that!
Just curious, what should I have searched in Google to get this answer? I searched "if/then range" but just got COUNTIF responses

Comment: I think including `if/then` in your searches confused matters. By its nature, `IF`  will only ever return 2 possible values. 
`Lookup` and `Vlookup` are very common Excel functions. Once you start to use them you'll never be without them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing it now, and for some weird reason, when I toggle through the dropdown in F1, it mixes up some of the fees. Not sure why it's doing this. The first 2 are correct, then 3 and onward are all mixed up. Some refer to the same fee and some come back 0. One even returns an `#N/A`

Comment: I think the issue is in this rule: *LOOKUP has default behaviors that make it useful when solving certain problems (i.e. retrieve approximate matched value instead of position, find the value in the last non-empty cell in a row or column, etc.). LOOKUP assumes that values in lookup_vector are sorted in ascending order and always performs an approximate match. When LOOKUP can't find a match, it will match the next smallest value.*

Comment: In that case you can use a combination of `index` and `match` to only look for an absolute match.
`=INDEX(E42:F56,MATCH(F1,F42:F56,0),1)`

Comment: Thank you, the `index` and `match` worked perfectly.
Just curious, what is the use of the `LOOKUP` formula?